# Fitting a Fireplace Surround

Tags: fireplace, installation

I want to replace an old fire place surround with a new fire place surround with a back plate and a hearth.

Having removed the old fire surround it appears that it has an old fire behind it, which has a lintel and concrete walls, that stand a little proud of the wall.

I purchase a new fireplace it will not sit flush.

Is there anything I can do to fix the gap?

Comment: "*it appears that it has an old fire behind it*"  an old fire?

Comment: A picture would be helpful.